# Loading an abstract class based object by YAML file

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I want to load object which contains array list of objects based on abstract class from yaml file. And i get this error message:

Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" Cannot create property=arrayListOfAbstractObjects for JavaBean=com.myyaml.test.ImplementationOfExampleClass@7a358cc1

in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
dummyLong: 1
^

java.lang.InstantiationException
in 'reader', line 3, column 3:
- dummyFloat: 444
^

YAML file

```
dummyLong: 1
arrayListOfAbstractObjects:
  - dummyFloat: 444
  - dummyDouble: 123
```

Java classes:

```
public abstract class ExampleClass {
    protected ArrayList<AbstractClass> arrayListOfAbstractObjects;
    protected long dummyLong = 111;
    
    public ExampleClass() {
    }

    public void setArrayListOfAbstractObjects(ArrayList<AbstractClass> arrayListOfAbstractObjects) {
        this.arrayListOfAbstractObjects = arrayListOfAbstractObjects;
    }

    public void setDummyLong(long dummyLong) {
        this.dummyLong = dummyLong;
    }
}
```

```
public class ImplementationOfExampleClass extends ExampleClass {
    
    public ImplementationOfExampleClass() {
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    private int dummyInt = 22;
    
    public AbstractClass() {
    }

    public void setDummyInt(int dummyInt) {
        this.dummyInt = dummyInt;
    }
}
```

```
public class FirstImplementationOfAbstractClass extends AbstractClass {
    float dummyFloat = 111f;
    
    public FirstImplementationOfAbstractClass() {
    }

    public void setDummyFloat(float dummyFloat) {
        this.dummyFloat = dummyFloat;
    }
}
```

```
public class SecondImplementationOfAbstractClass extends AbstractClass {
    double dummyDouble = 333f;
    
    public SecondImplementationOfAbstractClass() {
    }

    public void setDummyDouble(double dummyDouble) {
        this.dummyDouble = dummyDouble;
    }
}
```

My guess is that yaml doesn't know which sort of abstract class implementation to use. FirstImplementationOfAbstractClass or SecondImplementationOfAbstractClass. Is it possible to load an object by yaml with such classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible if you tell the YAML processor which class you want to instantiate on the YAML side. You do this with tags:

```yaml
dummyLong: 1
arrayListOfAbstractObjects:
  - !first
    dummyFloat: 444
  - !second
    dummyDouble: 123
```

Then, you can instruct your YAML processor to properly process the items based on their tags. E.g. with SnakeYAML, you would do

```java
class MyConstructor extends Constructor {
    public MyConstructor() {
        this.yamlConstructors.put(new Tag("!first"), new ConstructFirst());
        this.yamlConstructors.put(new Tag("!second"), new ConstructSecond());
    }

    private class ConstructFirst extends AbstractConstruct {
        public Object construct(Node node) {
            // raw values, as if you would have loaded the content into a generic map.
            final Map<Object, Object> values = constructMapping(node);
            final FirstImplementationOfAbstractClass ret =
                    new FirstImplementationOfAbstractClass();
            ret.setDummyFloat(Float.parseFloat(values.get("dummyFloat").toString()));
            return ret;
        }
    }

    private class ConstructSecond extends AbstractConstruct {
        public Object construct(Node node) {
            final Map<Object, Object> values = constructMapping(node);
            final SecondImplementationOfAbstractClass ret =
                    new SecondImplementationOfAbstractClass();
            ret.setDummyFloat(Double.parseDouble(values.get("dummyFloat").toString()));
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You can be more intelligent when loading the content, avoiding `toString` and instead process the node content directly; I use a dumb implementation for easy demonstration.

Then, you use this constructor:

```java
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new MyConstructor());
ExampleClass loaded = yaml.loadAs(input, ImplementationOfExampleClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Node class is kind of YAML file transformed into Java data object. I found under debugger it contains field `ArrayList<E>` value. Which contains NodeTuple with YAML file fields (e.g. dummyFloat). So I must in `constructMapping(node)` method convert on my own each field and then set them in e.g. `ConstructFirst.construct(Node node)` on the constructed object.

EDIT:

> So I must in `constructMapping(node)` method convert on my own each field and then set them in e.g. `ConstructFirst.construct(Node node)` on the constructed object.

Cast of param node to MappingNode is needed. This method is inherited from BaseConstructor.constructMapping(MappingNode node). Flyx didn't add that cast and I didn't know where to get it from. Thanks for help. Now it works. But i'm still struggle with nested abstract classes. Maybe i'll need help, but I will try to handle myself.

Also this link might be helpful:
[Polymorphic collections in SnakeYaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176025/polymorphic-collections-in-snakeyaml)